# Camel JMS recipientList goto wrong queue

Tags: apache-camel, jms, multicast

I have an issue with Camel.

I am creating dynamic queues like this

```
       for (Client client : clients) {
        // Get the ids
        String clientId = client.getId();
        String queueId = "jms:sendRoute" + clientId;
        // Generate the queues
        from(queueId)
                .routeId(queueId)
                .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(-1).redeliveryDelay(1000 * 60 * 5))        // Retries indefinitively
                .transacted()
                .process(new MyProcessor(clientId, clientService))
                .to("mock:end");

    }
```

Which are called by this initial route

```
from("direct:availabilityRoute")
              .routeId("availabilityRoute")
                .unmarshal(bindy)                                       
                .split(body())                                          
                .process(new AProcessor(controler))    
                .split(body())                                          
                .process(new DBProcessor(controler))  
                .process(new RoutesProcessor(controler)) 
                .recipientList(header("clientIds"), ",")
                .to("mock:end");
```

The route processor generates the list of queue ids to which a essage is multicasted

ids.append("jms:sendRoute" + client.getId());
and Ids (a string) is put in the message header

I am using activeMQ

I don't understand the behaviour

When it starts, it creates 3 routes dynamically. They are named:

sendRoute1
sendRoute2
sendRoute3

(this is what I see in the admin console)

The list of ids generated by the processor is: jms:sendRoute1,jms:sendRoute2, jms:sendRoute3

The issue I have is that when the message is sent to the multiple route, when I put a breakpoint I see that the first message is consumed by sendRoute1, and that 2 new routes named jms:sendRoute2 and jms:sendRoute3 have been added.
The message has been sent to:
- sendRoute1
- jms:sendRoute2
- jms:sendRoute3

But I have no consumer on jsm:sendRoute2 and jms:sendRoute3 so the messages are not read.

Could somebody explain me why this happens and how I can solve this?

Regards

Gilles

When a message is multicasted to all the queues in scope

Comment: You said **ids.append("jms:sendRoute" + client.getId()); and Ids (a string) is put in the message header** can you explain where and how you did it ? You don't append "," as you said **The list of ids generated by the processor is: jms:sendRoute1,jms:sendRoute2, jms:sendRoute3**

Comment: Have you logged the value returned by **header("clientIds")** , another thing to check is your routes names must be **jms:sendRoute1,jms:sendRoute2, jms:sendRoute3** and not what you seen in the admin console